# Tablet cam on: feedback using light

Tags: samsung, tablet, front-camera

I love the way my laptop indicates when the webcam is on by illuminating the LED next to the cam.

I wanted to try to get similar behaviour out of my Android tablet where it could indicate by some cue that the front cam was on. Maybe the LED blinking or something similar.

I find sometimes I may start a zoom call and then shift focus to a different app and it may not be obvious to me that the camera is still on.

Any way to achieve this? Either natively or using a third party app or script etc.

If it matters I am using the Samsung S6 Lite tab.

Comment: If you are ready to root, install xposed /EdXposed (depends on your Android version, please add that to question and tags), it may be possible using GravityBox premium version

Comment: Try this with [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation. Create a macro : Trigger Application closed - select zoom ;Action :1.Notification Led enable 2. Pop-up message :whatever pop up text you want // If you want this for other camera using apps too, add in trigger

Comment: There are specialized apps that can provide a notification icon if microphone/camera is active. See for example the app [Access Dots](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=you.in.spark.access.dots).